# How compiler generates correct version of a template function which parameter is know at runtime?

Tags: c++, templates, template-instantiation

I tried to declare a template class with parameters which types will be clear at runtime
and wanted to see will the code compile expecting that it won`t, since templates are instantiated at compile time and here the parameters are defined at runtime. But it compiles and works correctly.

I have:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    if (!a) {
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(a);
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::vector<char> v;
        v.push_back(a);
        std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it prints 'C' in case input is 67, so it works correctly.

Are used vector members instantiated at runtime ?
if not, how compiler instantiates the vector members ?

Comment: Do you realize that you compiled BOTH versions of the template, and that the shown code simply executed one of two alternative compiled versions of the same code? This is like saying "I have both a black and a white car in my garage, and when I chose to drive one of them today I must be somehow changing the color of my only car, to what I want".

Comment: But shouldn't only used members be instantiated ?
if vector<char>::push_back() is instantiated than vector<int>::push_back() shouldn`t be instantiated.

Comment: "Only used members are instantiated" this is correct, but "used" doesn't mean "only used at runtime"... -- it appears that you're pretty confused (but other than that, there's nothing wrong with questions coming from a misunderstanding of the OP unless it's a duplicate)

Comment: Instantiation of templates, and template methods and static methods occurs at compile time. The shown code uses both `vector<char>::push_back()` and `vector<int>::push_back()`, so your compiler instantiates both of them.

Comment: @NarekMeta At the risk of stating the obvious, but those `std::vector<int> v;` are two different variables, with different scopes and lifetimes. Just because you gave them the same name doesn't change any of that. For a simpler example, suppose you wrote  `std::cout << (!a ? "hello" : "world") << std::endl;`, then *both* string would be in the compiled program. They *have* to be, since it is not known which one will print until runtime. For the very same reason, both `if` and `else` branches of your code get compiled into the executable, regardless of which one gets executed when you run it.

Comment: Hi @user202729,  you pointed "only used at runtime" and that was where I had misunderstanding. Thank you.    Hi dxiv, already was clear for me, Thank you a lot,